# managing two libraries with cabal that depend on each other

Tags: haskell, recursion, libraries, cabal, cabal-install

I've got the following question:

I've got two Haskell libraries that depend on each other, and both libraries are managed by cabal. The corresponding cabal files look like this:

Library 1:

```
name:           Lib1
version:        0.1
cabal-version:  >=1.2
build-type:     Simple
author:         Matthias

library
  hs-source-dirs:  src
  build-depends:   
               base >= 4,
               Lib2
  ghc-options:     -Wall
  exposed-modules:   <...>
```

Library 2:

```
name:           Lib2
version:        0.1
cabal-version:  >=1.2
build-type:     Simple
author:         Matthias

library
  hs-source-dirs:  src
  build-depends:   
               base >= 4,
               Lib1
  ghc-options:     -Wall
  exposed-modules: <...>
```

Installing one of the libraries (here library 2) with `cabal install` works:

```
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following will be installed:
Lib2-0.1 (reinstall)
Warning: Note that reinstalls are always dangerous. Continuing anyway...
Configuring Lib2-0.1...
Building Lib2-0.1...
Preprocessing library Lib2-0.1...
Registering Lib2-0.1...
Installing library in
C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Roaming\cabal\Lib2-0.1\ghc-7.4.2
Registering Lib2-0.1...
```

But trying to install the other library (here library 1) with `cabal install` results in a dependency error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: Lib1-0.1 (user goal)
next goal: Lib2 (dependency of Lib1-0.1)
rejecting: Lib2-0.1/installed-aa4... (package is broken)
```

Is there any way to handle two such libraries that depend on each other so that I don't get dependency errors or is cabal simply not able to handle such a case properly?

Comment: I do not think that is ever going to work. Since Cabal is compiling the modules, you should need Lib1 to compile Lib2 and vice versa, so neither should be able to be installed first. Honestly, I cannot imagine how you got Lib2 to install--did you, by chance, have an installed earlier version of Lib1 that did not depend on Lib2? If you did, the moment Cabal tries to install Lib1 it will break Lib2 (which depends on Lib1). Try unregistering both packages (`ghc-pkg unregister`) and trying again--I suspect it will give a clearer set of errors.

Comment: Circular dependencies will only lead to trouble, if you can even get it to work at all. Break the cycle, either by moving some stuff from one package to the other, extracting common code into a third package, or joining the packages into one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the others have said, circular dependencies are never going to work in Cabal. It's hard enough to compile *modules* with circular dependencies, but *packages* are a hopeless cause.

It can be annoyingly difficult sometimes, but the only real solution is to find a way to break the circular dependency somehow.